# Is it possible to convert a string to the name of a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

Before we come to the actual question, I'll need you to understand my App.

I have a function add() which feeds integers based on the user's input into a list. This list of integers is fed into a function avg() which calculates the average of all the integers inside of the list.

This list however, is bound to a widget which can be added infinite. But before a title for that widget must also be provided by the user.

> Imagine it like that: You click on a floatingActionButton and a TextField opens. In that TextField you type in a title. After you submit the title a Box is crated with that title.
>
> Inside this Box you have the possibility to click a Button which opens a new TextField. In that textField you type in an integer between 0-15 which then is added to the list bound to the widget.

That's why I need a new list of integers to be created, whenever I create a the users creates a new Widget.

That's why I was wondering if there is a way to just take the String of the title (lets say 'my awesome title') and use that to define a new list with that string (my thoughts in code are below).

Something like this:

```
String title = 'title';
List<int> 'title' = [];
```

Everything I found regarding this topic, didn't really covered the answer I was looking for. So please excuse me if this question was asked in a similar way before. I probably didn't understood it, hopefully you can help me out better. :)

If it is not possible to convert a String to a list name, I would love to hear about a different technique which would solve the problem explained.

Comment: What should be in this list? Codes of characters?

Comment: It would be integers from 0 to 15 wich are being added in a different function.

Comment: So do you have a function that converts single character to int?

Comment: No, its a little different to that. I have a function wich feed in integers based on the user's input. Out of these integers an average is calculated. The Lists is bound to a widget wich can be added as often as you like. But therefor a title must be provided wich can't be existing more than once. Thats why I need a list of integers, where every list corresponding to the widget hast a different name, so that the users doesn't feed the same list from different widgets.

Comment: Well, please update you question and add more details. Right now it's unclear what exactly you need.

Comment: I'll do that :)

Comment: In python you can do that. but I never found way to do that in dart.  Instead you can use a `Map <String, dynamic>`

Comment: @KirillBubochkin I updated the question. Should I re-ask my question or just leave it edited?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly You want to save the value as a identifier/variable name and use that for fetching other values? like list of integers.

In that case thing which might suit your case would be Map or key/value pairs.

Lets say you got a String from server or any other way.

```
String title = await getStringFromServer();
List<int> data = await getIntegersfromSomewhere(title);
```

Now you might want the map to come in action. you can save these values in map.

```
final Map<String,List<int>> _map = Map();
map[title] = data;
```

Now your map will contain whatever string you got from the server or from anywhere. and corresponding list of integers.